# Using Matlab to receive the same coefficients as from the Filter Designer

Tags: matlab, filter, designer, coefficients

I am currently working with IIR Filter coefficients. So now I want to become a bit more agile as it is kind of cumbersome to type a lot of filters into the filter designer, then copy every value to transform the fixed Point representation into hexadecimal.

So I planned on writing a script. The problem I have is: I can't find a matlab function that provides the values in the same way as the filter designer does. For an 8th order IIR Filter, the Designer outputs the values for each section with a gain, 3 Numerator values and 3 denominator values as in the following picture.[image: Filter coefficients from Filter Designer]

Now, in Matlab I tried it with:

```
fs = 50000;      %Hz
fnormalize = 2/fs;
fstop1 = 1000*fnormalize; %Hz
fstop2 = 8000*fnormalize;
f1filter = 3000*fnormalize; %Hz
f2filter = 4000*fnormalize; %Hz

filterOrdnung = 4;  %erzeugt (2 * filterOrdnung) Filterkoeffizienten
                    %weil Kombination zwei Tiefpässen. 
anzahlFilter = 1;   %Anzahl der zu berechnenden Filter zur Auswertung
schrittweiteVerschiebung = 10;  %Verschiebung in Hz
astop = 60;           %Verstärkung an den Bandgrenzen des Bandpasses
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
frequenzVektor = zeros(1,anzahlFilter);     %f - Vektor für Mittenfrequenz


[z, p, k] = cheby2(filterOrdnung, astop, [f1filter f2filter], 'bandpass'); 

[sos, g] = zp2sos(z,p,k);                                               %Output form:[b01,b11,b21,1,a11,a21
                                                                        %             b02,b12,b22,1,a12,a22
                                                                        %             b0N,b1N...........a2N]
    %Also:  1. Zeile: Nullstellen Filter 1, Polstellen Filter 1,
    %       2. Zeile: Nullstellen Filter 2, Polstellen Filter 2 etc..
sos_quant = zeros(8,6);
for i = 1:filterOrdnung
    for k = 1 : 6
        sos_quant(i,k) = quantizenumeric(sos(i,k),1,16,14,'fix');   
    end
end
fvtool(sos);
```

But I am not receiving a gain for every section. Since I don't want to change my VHDL model if I don't have to, I wanted to ask you, if you know a function that gives me the information like the Filter Designer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the filter designer to generate the Matlab code for you. This should be exactly the same code the designer uses to find the coefficients. So I assume also the coefficients will be the same.

In the filter designer: `File -> Generate MATLAB code -> Filter design function`

So you can check for yourself for the differences to your code.

Comment: I tried it today, thank you! I did not know this option exists. After writing a script with the built in function, it is so much more comfortable to work with a lot of coefficients. I compared the filter values and they are identical now.